# PDF not getting generated using mpdf in php

Tags: php, mpdf

I am using mpdf library to generate pdf from html(table) content in php. I am using below code

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    $html=$_POST['html'];
    include 'mpdf.php';
    $mpdf=new mPDF(); 
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $mpdf->Output();
    exit;
    ?>
```

When the size of html table is small, say about 100 rows, then PDF is generated properly. But when size of table is more, say about 1000-2000 rows, then pdf is not generated.

Is there any size constraint in mpdf? What can be done to solve this problem? Or is there any other better library to generate pdf's in php

I have tried increasing memory allocated to 256,512 and 1024 mb in `php.ini` by using this code `ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');`
I also tried increasing time limit, it is now generating PDF but taking more time to generate and PC becomes slow. How can I release memory?

Comment: Have you tried setting a time limit?

Comment: Actually am not getting any time out error.Still do i need to set time limit?

Comment: Try and add a higher time-limit and see what happens.

Comment: It works on increasing time limit. It is taking so much time to generate PDF and making whole system slow. Is there any way that I can release the memory once pdf is generated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
ini_set("memory_limit", "2G");

$mpdf->packTableData = true;
```

And as usual, be wary of bad nesting, unclosed tags, improper escaping, or wrong colspan settings.
Check generated HTML code with http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: It is taking so much time to generate PDF and making whole system slow. Is there any way that I can release the memory once pdf is generated